# How can i get my related object from database?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have 2 classes:

```
    public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Pole nie może być puste")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Subcategory> Subcategories {get;set;}
}
    public class Subcategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Pole nie może być puste")]
    [DisplayName("Nazwa podkategorii")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

And I have got class where I am trying get my object "Category"

```
        public IEnumerable<Category> GetAllCategories()
    {
        return context.Categories.Include(c => c.Subcategories);
    }

    public Category GetCategory(int Id)
    {
        return context.Categories.Find(Id);
    }
```

Method GetAllCategories works fine, but when I use GetCategory I get only Category data without related object "Subcategory" list. Someone can help me with my problem? How can I get whole object?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include relations that you need:

```
public Category GetCategory(int Id)
{
    return context.Categories.Include(e => e.Subcategories).Single(e => e.Id == Id);
}
```

You can see more examples here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data